# Passing additional POST parameters every time a model is added to a store that has a 'api' config option

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Ext JS 4: Passing additional POST parameters every time a model is added to a store that has a 'api' config option

Case of use:

A typical store with:

```
api:{ read:url1.php, create:url2.php }
```

Including:

```
extraParams:{...}
```

to inform the .php script: sqlserver, log, pass, db, and table parameters.

Loading the store (api->read) will include these extraParams{...} as POST parameters in the HTTP request resulting in a successful Read operation.

Adding a model to the store (api->create) will only send the model (record) in the HTTP request, ignoring the extraParams:{...}, so my .php script will fail.

Is there a way to inform the .php script with the needed extra params?

Comment: Not with Ext4, they changed it so now extraParams are only sended in read but not in updates, i know, it sucks and its pretty stupid but they did it like that so we have to deal with it, you can override the buildRequest method (or the doRequest, the one that fits you better) in proxy to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: I did notice one caveat, it appears if you mark `read` as `'POST'` it doesn't attach the `extraParams` however, leaving it a `'GET'` request fixed that issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have a problem like your in ext4.0.7 so i create a method to save the json file.
To handle all parameter i make an ajax request like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'scripts/send.php',
        params: {stringapwd : stringa},
        method: 'POST',
    success: function (response){
        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {
            }
    });
```

see also:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

Comment: He didn't ask about generic Ajax request. He was asking about store with create/update interface.

Comment: i give him a different solution. that's all.

Comment: No. You gave him solution to a different problem. Entirely.